# Isolated web space for users using apache mod user_dir

Tags: linux, apache-http-server

I am wondering If docker could be used to perform this. So I have a website which I want to use as a cloud-storage provider (friends and family). But what is getting me annoyed is that maybe, some friend uploads a virus, a malicious php executable or something that could harm the root system. I am searching for a solution which grants a user some space to upload and download his files but that space needs to be completly separated and isolated from the system.

Docker volumes might be a solution, but since I run the server on a raspberry, using docker volumes would demand a high cpu demand.

Thanks!

Comment: Anyone has some hints?